# Private Unicode Character displays differently in Python 3 Interpreter

Tags: python, windows, unicode, python-3.4, python-idle

So I created a unicode character privately using **Private Character Editor** on Windows 10. The character was saved with the code `E000`. I copied it from the **Character Map** and pasted into a text editor and it worked. However, when I paste it into the Python IDLE editor it changes to a different unicode character, even before running the program. I can't use `u'unicode_string'` or anything like that because my unicode character doesn't even work in the interpreter. I am new to programming.

My question is, how do I *use* my private unicode character in Python 3.4?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j9iT.png) is what I see on Notepad.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iAtp.png) is what I see on Python 3.4 interpreter.

Comment: You probably don't have the right font in the IDLE Python editor, or the character is being rendered by a different font than the one you're expecting.

Comment: @nneonneo according to my character map i am using a font called **All Fonts (Private Characters)**. How do i change the IDLE Python editer font?

Comment: Can you try printing your character from the command-line Python interpreter, not using IDLE?

Comment: *Aside*: This is yet another reason why I do not use nor recommend IDLE.

Comment: This issue doesn't have to do with IDLE, and you can use custom characters in IDLE just as in the interpreter (which is really just embedded `cmd`). See my answer for more exposition.

Comment: @GregSchmit although I haven't studied the code itself, I'm quite sure IDLE doesn't use `cmd`. And I hope @Arbiter sees the latest comments at the end of your answer.

Comment: You're very right. I was saying that if you run python in Windows the interpreter will run inside `cmd`. IDLE uses a totally separate library, as I found out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449856/what-terminal-does-python-idle-use-on-windows/41450856#41450856

Comment: @Arbiter One can change IDLE's base editor font (which now depends on the OS) in the Settings dialog (Options => IDLE Preferences).  IDLE's user interface uses the tkinter (tk interface) module, which is a fairly light wrapper for the mostly OS-independent tcl/tk gui framework.  The list of fonts is provided by tk, which uses an OS-specific font lookup function.

Comment: CPython's use of Windows' console was greatly improved in 3.6 to handle non-ascii chars much better.  If one wants to print general unicode chars to the console, get 3.6.  IDLE's display of chars goes through tk.  Tk is limited to the Basic Multilingual Plane (scheduled to change in 2017), but prior to 3.6, tk and hence IDLE displayed unicode much better than the Windows' console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python isn't really the interesting part of this, rather the shell or terminal is. In our case, Windows uses special code points to represent private character encodings. To get those, you need to get a hex dump of the character on a shell in Windows, then you can render the character in Python.

**NOTE:** Use Unicode points `E021` or **higher**, since lower number code points are usually used for control, and it seems that the Windows shell that the python interpreter and IDLE use doesn't let you override those with private characters.

## Demonstration

I tested your issue by generating a private character of my own. I will put an image of my test here since it wouldn't be rendered properly in text here on Stack Overflow.

[image]

## Explanation

I used the `Character Map` program in Windows 10 to copy the symbol and paste it into my python environment. The environment may truncate it on the right since it is a wide character and the environment didn't seem to like that. (I moved the cursor around to get it to render full-width.)

Then I proceeded to get the hexdump of the code point by encoding the character using the default utf-8 encoding, which turned out to be `\xee\x80\xa1` as a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) object.

Next I printed the data as a string to show you a common error, and what would be printed if you attempted to print a string of those bytes.

Then, I printed `b'\xee\x80\xa1'`, which is how you would actually use the symbol in your software.

Comment: My **private unicode character (PUC)** works on text editors like `notepad`, and it works on `cmd` aswell. As well as not working within the Python interpreter, it doesn't work in the Python editor either. For example, if I copy and past my PUC from the `cmd` or `notepad` into Pythons editor, a new unicode character shows up, rather than my PUC that I want to use.

Comment: @Arbiter, I did a test, and the last line in the test is how I used the character in python. You should be able to follow the same steps to get the code point for your special character.

Comment: that works, but you said that you copied and pasted your character from the character map in Windows 10? I tried that, but as i paste the character from the character map into the editor (so that i can assign it to char and encode it) the character looks completely different. I then tried the rest of your code and it worked but  for this new character, not the one that i originally created. Why is Python automatically replacing my PUC with a random unicode character when i paste it from the character map?

Comment: @Arbiter I updated my answer to be more clear and I actually used IDLE since that was what you used. In Character Map ensure you click select and copy, and then pasting it into your terminal should work. Also, if you changed or added the character since you opened shell, then that particular terminal might not be able to render the character. Closing and re-opening IDLE would probably fix the issue.

Comment: i've updated my answer with an image doing **exactly** as you instructed with a similar picture, and still when i paste into IDLE a different unicode character pops up instead

Comment: I completely understand what you have demonstrated, yet despite my attempts to replicate your demonstration with my own custom unicode character, it still doesn't work. I have no idea why!

Comment: Ah, so the shell that the python interpreter and IDLE use isn't letting me override some of the code points, probably for control. Use codepoints that visible text is normally at anyway, like E0021 and higher. If you look at other fonts you'll notice they usually start there.

Comment: I went back into the unicode character editor and saved the **same character as before** into the spot `E021` and when i copied it from the character map and pasted it into IDLE (after closing it and reopening it as you recommended) a unicode house character appeared - again, a **completely different character** appeared after pasting my custom unicode chacater in IDLEs interactive window. Why?

Comment: I've seen your edit, so how do i get a code like `E0021`? I scroll down the codes in the private character editor but i can't see that code

Comment: I meant `E021`.

Comment: I tried `E021` and like i said, it didn't work. Should i try higher? I.e. `E025`

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue, but it very likely has to do with Windows being Windows. While you really should just uninstall Windows and install FreeBSD or some other Unix variant, if I were you and I wanted to use Windows custom fonts this bad, I would reboot my machine, enable developer tools and Bash, and reinstall python so you're at the latest version (3.6).

Comment: And yes, you should try higher numbered codepoints like E025 or E040 to see if you can get those to work for you.

Comment: I tried higher and it didn't work. Perhaps it is my Python version - never thought about it that way. Perhaps Python 3.4 does not have support for custom unicode characters

Comment: It does, I tested that already. But update anyway since it might be a transient problem that is fixed by upgrading your python installation.

Comment: Hold up, i tried a much higher codepoint and it worked - i tried `E7C2`

Comment: Windows might be more restrictive if you don't have developer mode enabled, but I'm glad that you got it to work for you on at least one codepoint.

Comment: Yes, that codepoint is fine for me. I will now retry your demonstartion in order to use the PUC in my program. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You're getting different symbols for the low ranges of PUA characters because you already have a font that defines glyphs for them for its own purposes, and fallback between different fonts varies wildly across applications. (The font appearing in the screenshot is Gabriola.) This is always going to be a problem; if you need this to be reliable, and especially if you need it to work for anyone else, Private Use characters aren't your answer.

Comment: @bobince Good point, I should have mentioned before that private use characters are a Bad Idea.

Comment: After experimenting, I succeeded in printing a private char in IDLE with `print('\ue306')`.  The `print` is needed even in the shell to avoid the `repr` expansion back to '\ue306' that happens with expression echoing.  I used e306 because it was not previously in use on my machine with Lucida Console.  I determined that by printing a large range of private use chars and looking for the 'missing glyph' box used by tk.  In Private Char Editor, I stuck with () Link All Fonts because I could not figure out how to link to just one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\u` escape sequence in your Python source code, like so:

```
my_unicode_string = 'This is my Unicode character: \ue000'
print(my_unicode_string)
```

Comment: That works to print a unicode character, but it doesn't print the unicode character that i have created. Instead, it prints a random unicode character. I'll attach some screenshots to my question

Comment: @Arbiter: That's a different problem which deserves a separate question. If your output console cannot display a character, you'll have to set up your output console to use the correct font. This is unrelated to this question.

Comment: @llnspectable it isn't just that, the Python editor replaces my character with another random unicode character, before i even run the program

Comment: See my attached images for clarification. You can see that on `notepad` my private unicode character shows up, but in Python (both the editor and output console) show a completely different unicode character. This new character appears instantaneously when i paste my PUC from `notepad` when it shouldn't, it should be exactly the same as the character i copied in the first place.