# What Terminal does Python IDLE use on Windows

Tags: python, windows, shell, terminal, python-idle

I was [helping a fellow Stack Overflow-er today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447166/private-unicode-character-displays-differently-in-python-3-interpreter/41448016#41448016) and I noticed that I don't know what terminal `IDLE` uses in Windows. I am tacitly assuming that Python didn't write their own terminal for Windows, and that they probably use an API that gives them some version of `cmd` or `powershell`. I verified that the interpreter runs on `cmd`, but I don't know about `IDLE`.

What terminal does `IDLE` use in Windows?

Comment: Huh? Do you mean "terminal" instead of "shell"? If so, you can find the source easily -- it's written in Python using Tkinter, and *is* in fact written just for IDLE.

Comment: Frankly, most of what makes writing a terminal emulator hard is needing to... well... *emulate terminal protocols*. If you're wrapping software that you wrote yourself and you don't need to be compatible with ancient hardware terminals with protocols written to run over serial lines (and decades of hacks meant to allow more features on top of those terminals), it's not such a daunting task. Telling a preexisting rich-text widget how to behave is downright *easy*.

Comment: ...if you really do mean "shell" rather than "terminal", by contrast, the question just doesn't make any sense. Why do you expect any significant changes to need to be made when porting the REPL across platforms at all?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I clarified my question and why I think 'shell' is the word I'm looking for. I could be wrong though so if I have conflated the two terms then please correct me. I thought the terminal was just the middleware that connects my keyboard/video to the real software that processes everything (the shell). So in this case, I'm wondering the shell that is used because that would determine why the characters showed up differently. Although the terminal would play a big role there too.

Comment: ...so... you're conflating differences in shell behavior with terminal behavior. Shells that strictly conform with POSIX don't honor `echo -e` as telling them to do anything other than emit the literal string `-e` on output (bash is bad about this by default, but *can* be compliant when the `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags are both set). If you want to force a POSIX (non-csh) shell to interpret an escape sequence, use `printf '%b'`.

Comment: Ah, ok, so then the behavior in Windows I am describing would be terminal behavior?

Comment: ...now, taking what that shell has written out, and then actually recognizing color codes and colorizing output is terminal work. But to distinguish between what the shell is doing and what the terminal is doing, you need to make sure your shell scripts written in different languages are actually consistent.

Comment: Correct -- the actual rendering is done by the terminal, not the shell. The shell just generates a stream of bytes, and the terminal recognizes some of those bytes as instructions to clear the screen, change colors, update the window title, whatever.

Comment: (This is why you can use the same shell over a serial line as in a graphical window, and it doesn't know or care about the difference -- heck, if you had a physical [DEC VT100 terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) on the other end of that serial line, the shell would be generating the **exact** same sequences as if you had a terminal emulator in VT100 mode, and wouldn't know or care about the difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDLE is not built on an external shell or terminal, but on the [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) GUI toolkit.

The source code to the editor window can be read [here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/idlelib/EditorWindow.py); for the interactive shell, see [here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/idlelib/PyShell.py).

Comment: I verified that the interpreter runs on `cmd`, so I trimmed my question down. Thanks for clearing up my question via dialogue.

Comment: @GregSchmit, cmd.exe is neither a console nor a terminal and python.exe does not run on it. Any Windows application can attach to a console (conhost.exe), but console applications such as cmd.exe, powershell.exe, and python.exe are flagged to attach to a console automatically when run, which is either inherited from the parent process or newly allocated.

Comment: @eryksun So then this is a semantic issue I think. What do you call the black box that `.exe` files that are compiled to run in the command-line show up in? I call it `cmd` or 'Command prompt'. Is there another term? Is that what you meant by `conhost.exe`?

Comment: @eryksun I would think that `cmd.exe` would be considered a terminal for sure (since it is rendering a command-line interface to me) and wouldn't it also be a shell, since it processes commands and returns back data?

Comment: @GregSchmit, it's called a console window, which is hosted by an instance of conhost.exe. It has nothing to do with cmd.exe, other than the fact that cmd is also a console application that will attach to (either inherit or allocate) a console automatically at startup, unless, like any console app, it's started with the `CreateProcess` creation flag `DETACHED_PROCESS` (8). If you run python.exe via the Win+R dialog, you'll see two processes created (in Windows 7+): python.exe and conhost.exe.

Comment: @GregSchmit, ...think about how on a Unix, you might have xterm with bash inside it (but you could also have an xterm directly running something else, like a Python interpreter, with no shell between the two); on Windows, you get `conhost` with `cmd` inside it (or not).

Comment: @GregSchmit, cmd.exe doesn't render its interface. It writes to its Windows standard handles, `StandardOutput` and `StandardError`, and reads from `StandardInput`. It can be run detached from a console using pipes for standard I/O.